# How to install PyCRC module?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I tried to install [PyCRC](https://pycrc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) module in venv on my Windows machine. Before I already used this module in same machine but not installed it in venv, and on Linux machines I used it too and everything was fine.
But now I can not install it.

`pip install PyCRC`

And I got another module with same name - https://pypi.org/project/pycrc/.
What wrong here? How can I get module what I needed?

Answer (score 3):

I have been having the same issue and I eventually found that the PyCRC module is listed as 'pythoncrc' (it has the right Author and latest version).

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycrc/), the pycrc module hosted right now on PyPI doesn't have the same author as the link you provided, digging a little bit, you can notice the original author has deleted his github account and the source code of the original PyCRC can now be found [here](https://github.com/alexbutirskiy/PyCRC), but since the name PyCRC was already taken, the [current maintainer](https://pypi.org/user/jakehill/) changed the name on PyPI to 'pythoncrc' hence:

```
pip install pythoncrc
```